# Casio CW16 Typewriter

Tags: printer

I am in need to refill my typewriter with more ink (this model uses ink ribbons), but in the place where I live they don't sell those ink ribbons anymore. I am considering to buy some cheap nylon ribbons, and soak them in normal ink, then attach those new inked nylon ribbons back to the ink ribbon. Would it work? I hear if you re-ink an old typewriter ink ribbon it wears out, that's why I'm buying the nylon ribbons. Would these, the inked nylon ribbons work?

Comment: Voting to reopen as this typewriter "has a microprocessor in it." https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181/are-questions-about-calculators-on-topic

Comment: Fridges and washing machines have microprocessors in them, are they computers>

Comment: I'd recommend asking this on Lifehacks.SE

Answer (score 4):

AFAIR the CasioWriter 16 does **not** use ink ribbons, as it's not impact based. The CW-16, like the whole CW-1x series, uses a thermo head, thus only thermo paper (fax paper), or a transfer ribbon, can be used.

Are you sure it's a CW-16? The CW-650 series for example would be impact based using a daisy wheel print head.

Classic (impact) typewriter ribbons are made of cloth and reinking has always been the method of choice. Reinking itself does not damage the ribbon at all, it gets worn out from the types hitting it.